# Can JavaScript Librarys and programming languages work together?

Tags: javascript, programming-languages

Well, can they? Like jQuery using a fadeIn function for something on a C++ app, can it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confused about what runs where.

jQuery usually requires a browser with a Document Object Model to run.

While this is something a C++ application could probably, theoretically, provide somehow, it's not really practical.

You want to investigate UI and effects libraries native to C++ rather than JavaScript libraries.

What do you want do achieve and most importantly, on what platform?

Comment: Can C++ create animations like accordions and fade ins?

Comment: @Kawohi yes, it can. Usually with the help of a UI library of some sort because you don't want to do everything from scratch. jQuery however is not suitable for this because it is a specialized library designed to work inside a browser, an environment fundamentally different from a C++ app

Comment: +1! @Kawohi: You need a totally different code base for C++ applications. It requires a UI toolkit like GTK or QT to run a graphical C++ app. Those have very few in common with a web-based application and jQuery is not really what you need there.

Answer (score 1):

It would require your C++ app to contain both a JavaScript interpreter and a HTML DOM (because that's what jQuery operates on to do things like fadein effects).

Such C++ apps exist - they're called web-browsers. I suppose you could embed an open source web engine like Webkit in your app, but at that point you'd basically be developing a webapp and might as well drop the C++ part altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If your C++ application use [WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040%28VS.85%29.aspx) for example to display a web page which use [jQuery.fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) then you can "combine" both technologies.

Nevertheless I would more see that [jQuery.fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) will work parallel to your main application and they will not work really together.